# Can you have a 2Darray pointer within a struct in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have made a 2D array  of strings with pointers and I'm wondering how and if you can put this 2D array table with also an int ID into a struct. Having the struct be giving a sizeOf so theres a number of structs with unique tables the user entered the information for, so you can search the ID the user puts in a print the table of strings they put in as well. This is an idea i thought of i would like to know if it's a practice or nonsense.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//functions array of strings

void readStringArray(char** table, int rows); // only need rows and columns when it's a string
void printStringArray(char** table, int rows);

void main() 
{

    char** names;
    int row, col;
    int i;

    printf("Please enter the number of rows and columns\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);

    names = (char**)malloc(row * sizeof(char*)); 

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {

         
        *(names+i) = (char*)malloc(col * sizeof(char)); 

    }


    // functions 
    readStringArray(names, row);
    printStringArray(names, row);


}// main


void readStringArray(char** table, int rows) {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        printf("please enter row %d\n", i);
        scanf("%s", *(table + i)); // enters in the whole row

    }


}
void printStringArray(char** table, int rows) {
    
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        printf("The string on row %d is %s\n", i, *(table + i));

    }

}
```

Comment: If you store the 2D char array in a struct (as a `char**`), you would have to keep the number of rows and columns as members of the struct too. Otherwise it won't be possible to know the size of the allocated array each time.

Comment: There's a lot of ways you can go in C, including allocating the struct to a calculated size so you can actually store a table of characters in one block of memory. You just need to keep track of your offsets

Comment: Understand `char**` has NOTHING to do with an array. It is a single *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char` (one pointer to another pointer). You can *Simulate* a 2D array by having the pointer point to a block of memory holding multiple pointers which you then access as, e.g. `name[0], name[1], ...`. If you allocate storage for a block of characters and assign the starting address to one of the pointers, you can access each character as, e.g. `name[0][0], name[0][1], ...` emulating how you would index a 2D array. YES, you can make this a member of a `struct` along with `size_t size;`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do. But you can definitely have an array of strings within a struct. You say "2D array of strings" but I think you mean an array of strings or a 2d array of `char`s as strings are just `char` arrays in C, i.e.

```c
// 2D array of strings
char*** table1;

// 2D array of chars
char** table2;
```

To have an array of strings in a struct an example API could be:

```c
struct Table {
    int id;
    char** strings;
    int nstrings;
}

/// Initialize table
///
/// Allocate memory for `table->strings`, set id and nstrings.
int table_init(struct Table *table, int id, int nstrings);

/// Clear table
///
/// Free all internal memory in table
int table_free(struct Table *table);

/// Set the value of a string
///
/// Set the value of a string in the table. If value exists, free memory and
/// reallocate, otherwise allocate and copy in. Return error code on invalid
/// string number.
int table_set_string(struct Table *table, int stringnum, const char* s);

/// Get a string in the table
///
/// Return NULL on invalid stringnum
const char* table_get_string(struct Table *table, int stringnum);

/// Print the table contents to stdout
///
/// Alternatively, you could take a `FILE *stream` to go to file or stderr
void table_dump(struct Table* table);


/// Function to take an array of tables and return pointer to table with 
/// corresponding ID
/// 
/// Returns NULL on not found
struct Table find_table(struct Table *tables, int ntables, int id);

int main() {
    // this is your set of tables
    struct Table table_arr[N_TABLES];

    /*
        Build tables from input...
    */

    int id = /* prompt for id */;
    struct Table *table = find_table(table_arr, N_TABLES, id);
    table_dump(table);

    return 0;
}
```

Whether it's a practice? Sure, you're on a line of reasoning that leads ultimately to [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) which would provide for fast lookup by "id" to return a certain element. If you're curious I would read more in to those as they're one of the fundamental data structures of computation.

Comment: Note: `char*** table1;` or `char** table2;` have nothing whatsoever to do with an array. (see comment under question)